# MySQL SELECT query string split search value

Tags: mysql, sql, string, match

I have a MySQL column set up the following

daterange = 02/27/2017 - 02/29/2017

Now I would like to

```
SELECT * FROM leaves WHERE daterange (>= firstvalue && <= secondvalue)
```

Is this possible to do? Split each value since they're saved as one string?Otherwise, I guess I will have to split up the daterange before it is inserted into the table.

Comment: which data type are daterange  , firstvalue and secondvalue?

Comment: @Chad . . . split the date range before it is inserted into the table.  Don't create bogosity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the daterange, firstvalue and secondvalue  are proper date (datetime) data type you can use between

```
SELECT * 
FROM leaves 
WHERE daterange BETWEEN  firstvalue AND  secondvalue
```

if some  the values involed is not date  data type  but varchar you  should proper convert using a str_to_date or

Comment: Thanks, however firstvalue and secondvalue values do not exist, only the daterange does, and it is literally stored as "02/27/2017 - 02/29/2017" varchar type. Guess that isn't possible, huh?

Comment: so you should split the string in two proper part .. .. for obatin the tow distinct value ..?  .

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your data structure.  Here are things that are wrong with storing the range like that:

- Dates should be stored in native format (`date` or `datetime`), not strings.
- Columns should have a single value.
- Having to do string manipulations on a column generally precludes the use of indexes.

That said, sometimes you are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  So, if you are totally unable to fix the data structure, there is a work-around.  You can convert the range to the values you need:

```
where $date >= str_to_date(left(daterange, 10), '%m-%d-%Y') and
      $date <= str_to_date(right(daterange, 10), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree, the data structure is totally messed up, I am trying to revamp somebody else's project. I'll give this a go.